# Searching for Owl sounds

Tags: effects, libraries, sfx

I'm looking through a few sound libraries now for some owl sound effects.  Here are some refferences of the sounds I need:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=akwc82DOb4k

and

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1fKVE3_smYE&feature=related

I've been asked to use these sounds in creating an alien screech.  If anyone knows of other sounds that are similar to this please let me know.  Ideally I'm looking to find a small SFX pack (or you can create one to sell to me, I do not have the resources to record these sounds on my own).

Please post links and ideas.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

- A great link for cleaner owl recordings can be found here (I think you can download these):

http://www.soundboard.com/sb/Owl_hoot_sound.aspx

- For an online library of field recordings cataloging owls look here:

http://www.junglewalk.com/sound/owl-sounds.htm

Answer (score 0):

When I think owl, I think wizard…so maybe you can use a magic spell sound instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://aquinn.co.uk/wordpress/?p=347

Thought this was incredible first time I heard it.

Answer (score 0):

Just typed owl at sounddogs.com, it came back 415 search results. There's gotta be something in there. If not, you can also try Animal Trax from Hollywood Edge (hollywoodedge.com)
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The largest [library](http://www.birds.cornell.edu/netcommunity/page.aspx?pid=1676) of bird recordings in the world. They've been known to license recordings for sound design.

Looks like they have 2467 recording of owls or "Strigiformes."

Comment: @Justin Pearson - Awesome! That's a fantastic resource. And great to know that owls are in the Strigiformes order! You never know when someone will need to know that fact!